stack variable addressing in assembly
I started learning assembly not long ago, and I'm confused of the addressing of the stack variable:
main:

  ;.....

  push    dword 1
  push    dword 2
  push    dword 3
  
  call    test

  xor     rax, rax
  call    ExitProcess

test:
  ;access the dword values

After some test, I found these 3 dwords are accessible at rsp+8,rsp+16,rsp+24 respectively, why? Is it the effect of alignment(at 8 bytes)?
I'm using nasm and link.exe(by visual studio) in Windows 10 64bit.

You can't push a dword in 64 bit mode. It will be sign extended to 64 bits (8 bytes).
